# java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.Database

Tags: android, android-service, android-source

when I am trying to build the Database for my component it is throwing an exception like Database_Impl does not.

We have added below libraries

"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

Still we are facing above exception,
Could you please any one help us to resolve above error

Comment: What database are you using? Room? Are you sure the dependency above is enough?

Comment: If you are using room, you should be using these.     api "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:"+ project.ext.kaptVersion
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:"+ project.ext.kaptVersion
    kaptTest "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:"+ project.ext.kaptVersion

Comment: Please add your complete logcat and also share what kind of database you wish to use ?